# Is there a way to get list of languages, countries, regions, and cities supported in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, country

I need to be able to post with targets set (country, language, city and region) on a page (not for Ads), but can't seem to find a way to make sure the values I pass to Facebook actually mean something to Facebook, is there an API method to get supported elements?

Or is it so (unable to verify this) that these values take free-text, and somehow, facebook admins take care of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is:

countries:
http://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adcountry

languages: 
https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

Comment: as of May 2017, Facebook removed this file from their servers. I could not find where the XML file went or if it's just gone.

Comment: It's still morning over here, I don't want to use false language but we all know how it goes, facebook are ************ ** * **!